# Pygame playing sound with pygame.mixer.music.load(file) gives NoneType error

Tags: python, audio, pygame, nonetype

I've tried everything but i can't seem to get the file to play

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, codecs, os
class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.get = dict()
        execfile('audio.conf', self.get)
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        pygame.init()
        self.currentlyBusy=0
        self.songs = list()
        self.nextSong = None
        self.soundInst=None
        self.sLib = None
        self.count = 0
        self.SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    def startPlaying(self, loop=False):
        if self.get['currentSong'] != None:
           if self.currentlyBusy != 1:
               self.play()
               self.currentlyBusy = 1
               else:
                 if self.currentlyBusy == 1 and loop == False:
                 self.stopPlaying()
                 self.play()
    def continueNextSong(self):
        with codecs.open('playlist.db', 'r', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                self.songs.append(line.strip())
                if len(self.songs) == self.count:
                    self.count = 0
                    self.nextSong = self.songs[self.count]
                else:
                    self.nextSong = self.songs[self.count]
    def play(self):
        if len(self.songs) > 0: pass

        else:
           with codecs.open('playlist.db', 'r', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
                           for line in f.readlines():
                                   self.songs.append(line.strip())
                       self.currentlyBusy = 1
                       path=self.songs[self.count]
                       self.sLib = {}
                       sound = self.sLib.get(path)
                       if sound == None:
                         cpath = path.replace('/', os.sep).replace('\\', os.sep)
                         sound = pygame.mixer.music.load(str(cpath))
                         print cpath
                         self.sLib[path] = sound
                         self.soundInst = self.sLib[path]
                         sound.play()
    def stopPlaying(self):
         self.soundInst.stop()
         self.currentlyBusy = 0
    def __START_PLAYER_SERVICE__(self):
         pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(self.SONG_END)
         self.startPlaying(True)
         while True:
            for evt in pygame.event.get():
                if evt.type == self.SONG_END:
                    if self.get['loop'] == True:
                        self.playLastSong()
                     else:
                        if self.get['ploop'] == True:
                            self.count +=1
                            self.continueNextSong()

    def reload(self):
        execfile('audio.conf', self.get)
    def update(self):
            with codecs.open(self.config, 'wb', "utf-8-sig") as f:
                        song = self.get['currentSong']
                        w= '''
# LOOP THE SONG
loop=%s
# THIS IS JUST A TEXT FILE WITH FILE PATHS OF SONGS
playlist='%s'
# GETS MUSIC FROM THIS DIRECTORY
setMusicDir='%s'
# LOOP THE PLAYLIST
ploop=%s
# CURRENT SONG THE GUI WILL UPDATE THIS
currentSong='%s'
# THIS IS FOR THE VOLUME COMMANDLINE TOOL
# IF YOU DO NOT HAVE "gnome-alsa-mixer" AND "python-alsaaudio" DO NOT ACTIVATE
aSound=%s
# THIS IS A PYTHON SCRIPT THAT CONTROLS THE AUDIO VIA TERMINAL
volumeCommandTool='%s'
# THIS WILL JUST CONTROL VOLUME VIA GUI
volumeGuiControl='%s'
guiPID=%i
playerPID=%i
''' % (self.get['loop'], self.get['playlist'], self.get['setMusicDir'], self.get['ploop'], song, self.get['aSound'], self.get['volumeCommandTool'], self.get['volumeGuiControl'], self.get['guiPID'], self.pid)
                       f.write(u""+w)
                       f.close()
           self.reload()    
if __name__=="__main__":
    self = player()
    self.__START_PLAYER_SERVICE__()
```

when the script runs if there is a value for currentSong in config.conf then it should play, if there is no value then the first file in self.songs will play. But when I call,

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(self.song[self.count])
```

I get an error saying,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "player.py", line 100, in <module>
    self.__START_PLAYER_SERVICE__()
  File "player.py", line 58, in __START_PLAYER_SERVICE__
    self.startPlaying(True)
  File "player.py", line 19, in startPlaying
    self.play()
  File "player.py", line 52, in play
    sound.play()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

but I don't know how to fix this. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64AMD

Comment: @bmandesign I love you so much i've spent hours on this now everything should work with my GUI the gui just posts to the config and the player.py catches it

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong and can not currently test this, but try:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(str(cpath))
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

pygame.mixer.music.load() returns None

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(str(cpath))
```

It does not return a sound object. You can say pygame.mixer.music.play() and it will play the currently loaded music.

Or:

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(str(cpath))
channel = sound.play()
```

It is possible to load multiple sounds and it allows playing around with the channel object.